# Leap year checker failing unknown test cases

Tags: python

I'm using `Sololearn` to learn Python and I got stuck with that exercise.

> Task conditions: You need to make a program to take a year as input and output "Leap year" if it’s a leap year, and "Not a leap year", if it’s not.

> To check whether a year is a leap year or not, you need to check the following:

1. If the year is evenly divisible by 4, go to step 2. Otherwise, the year is NOT a leap year.
2. If the year is evenly divisible by 100, go to step 3. Otherwise, the year is a leap year.
3. If the year is evenly divisible by 400, the year is a leap year. Otherwise, it is not a leap year.

My code:

[image]

Sololearn is hiding some test cases to avoid cheating. There are 7 test cases and 2 of them is failed.

What am I missing?

Comment: So what is the main question

Comment: What problems are you facing? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68964235/edit) your question to include it.

Comment: Look at your logic - according to your code only years divisible by 4, 100 and 400 are leap years - and that is wrong. A leap year is any non-century year which is divisible by 4 and any century year that is divisible by 400. Your logic is wrong and your rules seem to be right.

Comment: Your second else statement is still a leap year. Read the number 2 again

Comment: Reverse the logic, test for 400, then 100 and finally 4.

Comment: I am concerned that your code is failing 'unknown' test cases ... you should be implementing your test cases so that you know exactly when it is failing - and if that means implementing your own test cases so be it. Detecting leap years is an easy problem to test as the right answer is easy to find on any given input year

Comment: @Bib - no need to do that - just need to correct one print statement - it is upto the OP to identify which one since this is clearly homework.

Comment: @Tony, it's easier to test 400, then else test for 100 then else test for 4. Nesting if's like this is asking for trouble. You should always test the most specific first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you should rethink your code: if we input the year 4 (which is a leap year) what will the output of your code be?

Here is the rule to know if a year is a leap year:

To be a leap year, the year number must be divisible by four – except for end-of-century years, which must be divisible by 400. This means that the year 2000 was a leap year, although 1900 was not. 2020, 2024 and 2028 are all leap years.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your step 2 in your rules and how you have implemented that in your code.

According to your rules 2024 is a leap year - but your code says it isn't.

I wont give you the corrected code, because this is almost certainly homework, but you haven't implemented step 2 correctly.